# Firebase and Typescript: Setting reference to admin.database() causes mocha tests to hang

Tags: typescript, firebase-realtime-database, mocha.js, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm using mocha, chai, and chaiAsPromised to test Firebase functions. I've been having a problem with my tests hanging: they run and succeed or as expected, but they don't complete. That is, I have to actually kill the test process to (Ctrl-C or F5) after the tests run.

For this code I'm using the Firebase Admin SDK, and I isolated the issue to a call to `admin.database`. I set up the following simplified test to isolate this hanging behavior:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import {} from 'mocha';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

let db: admin.database.Database;
before (() => {
  chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
  chai.should();

  admin.initializeApp(testConfig);
  db = admin.database();
});

describe('Data Access Tests', () => {  
  it ('tests DAO functionality', () => {
    return true;
  });  
});
```

When I include the line `admin.database()`, the test run hangs (i.e. the process never returns and I have to kill it with Ctrl-C.)
When I comment out the line `admin.database()`, **the test run completes**.
The test *always* "passes" (as expected, since it's just returning `true`.)

Though I don't necessarily need to set a reference to `admin.database()` like I do (it's just so I don't have to keep typing out the whole thing), I *do* need to pass `admin.database()` to my `DataAccessObject`, as that's where I've encapsulated all of the firebase database calls and it keeps all of those URL-based paths contained in one place.

Can anyone explain why the `admin.database()` call would cause the mocha process to hang?

Comment: Did you solve this?